# Simple way to prove telescopic identity $a^{n+1} − b^{n+1} = (a − b) \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a^{n-i} b^i$

Tags: real-analysis

Trying to prove the **Telescopic Identity**, but am getting it totally confused with Newton's Binomial Theorem. Does anyone know of a simple way to go about proving this?

$$a^{n+1} − b^{n+1} = (a − b) \sum_{i=0}^n a^{n-i} b^i$$

Comment: It really helps to write out an example with a specific n, say n = 4, to see what's going on. Just multiply out.

Comment: I would begin to symbolically divide the lhs by $(a-b)$

Comment: $$a\sum_{i=0}^n a^{n-i} b^i-b\sum_{i=0}^n a^{n-i} b^i=\sum_{i=0}^n a^{n-i+1} b^i-\sum_{i=0}^n a^{n-i} b^{i+1}=\sum_{i=0}^n a^{n-i+1} b^i-\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} a^{n-j+1} b^j=\ldots$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that the polynomial (in $a$) given by $a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}$ has a factor of $(a-b)$.  Performing synthetic division...

$$\begin{array}
{r|r r}b & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -b^{n+1} \\
& \downarrow & b & b^2 & \dots & b^n & b^{n+1} \\
\hline & 1 & b & b^2 & \dots & b^n & 0
\end{array}$$

Then you plug in all the $a$'s to get...

$$a^n+ba^{n-1}+b^2a^{n-2}+\dots b^{n-1}a+b^n=\sum_{k=0}^na^{n-k}b^k$$

Comment: Not really what I wanted...I would like a more rigorous explanation, starting with $a^{n+1} - b^{n+1}$ and finishing with $$(a - b) \sum_{i=0}^na^{n-i}b^i$$

Comment: @Ravmcgav How is this now?

Comment: Great! Thanks so much